# Providing unique text value in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm hardcoding username value for signup page username textbox. How to provide unique username value using selenium webdriver ?.

Example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Pinklin") ;
```

Since "Pinklin" is hardcoded, if the same script is run the second time it will throw username already exists error.

What are the ways in which a unique value could be provided if hardcoded.

Comment: Value is either hardcoded or it is dynamic, can't be both. You could have a popup input box.

Comment: Popup input textbox means providing value at runtime ? (I'm a newbie to selenium)

Comment: I misunderstood the requirement. Answer by Albert Waninge looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: do not (fully) hardcode this value.

You could use the following:

```
String username = "Pinklin" + new Random().nextInt(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
```

If you later on need to check on persisted values for username, you can either store this dynamically generated username, or you do a check with

```
username.startsWith("Pinklin")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better create one class to generate random name as shown [here](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/random/string/) and use this class in your test

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(msr.generateRandomString());//as per example mentioned in the above article
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are testing signup just send `System.currentTimeMillis()` as an username.